# What is queue.dequeue_up_to() method in tensorflow.data_flow_ops used for?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I've been really really confused with this method, especially when I found this puzzling statement:

```
output.set_shape(tensor_shape.TensorShape([None]).concatenate(shape))
```

Here are some comments as descriptions for the method:

```
This operation concatenates queue-element component tensors along
the 0th dimension to make a single component tensor. If the queue
has not been closed, all of the components in the dequeued tuple
will have size `n` in the 0th dimension.
```

It is so strange to specify a None to the 0th dimension of the shape(I suppose it could be n?), which seems to contradict with the *size 'n'* in the description. This has caused a Shape Error on my program and I can't just understand the reason, though I've found where it is.

Could you tell my why to use a `TensorShape([None])` here?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`QueueBase.dequeue_up_to(n)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/QueueBase#dequeue_up_to) method returns a batch of **at most** ("up to") `n` elements from the queue. By contrast the [`QueueBase.dequeue_many(n)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/QueueBase#dequeue_many) method returns a batch of **exactly** `n` elements from the queue.

The two operations behave the same until the queue is [closed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/QueueBase#close). After this point, no more elements can be added to the queue, so these operations will drain the remaining elements. If the number of remaining elements (`num_remaining`) is not an exact multiple of `n`, `QueueBase.dequeue_up_to(n)` will return a final smaller batch of `num_remaining % n` elements. By contrast, `QueueBase.dequeue_many(n)` will not return those last few elements, because it cannot make a batch of exactly `n` elements.

Since `QueueBase.dequeue_up_to(n)` can return batches of different sizes (i.e. `n` and `num_remaining % n`) that are not statically known (because `num_remaining` depends on the number of enqueue operations that happen at run-time), the first dimensions of its return values are `Dimension(None)`. `Dimension(None)` is typically used to indicate a shape that can vary between executions.